# Is it possible to make a 302 redirect request from AWS lambda to S3 bucket for triggering download?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to trigger a download when a POST request is made to my API gateway+Lambda setup. I've read that this is done by converting the file to base64. But is it possible to write the file to an S3 bucket and trigger a redirect?

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def main(event, context):
    s3.upload_file(PATH,BUCKET_NAME,FILE_NAME)
    # Make file accessable via URL and return redirect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It definitely is! I'm no good at Python, but the steps are rather simple

1. Configure your API Gateway as Proxy Integration, so that your Lambda function can set the return code (see [Set up a Proxy Integration with a Proxy Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html) and [Serverless.com - Lambda Proxy Integration](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#lambda-proxy-integration)
2. Upload your file to your S3 bucket
3. Make sure the file is accessible by the user. A bucket can be public, or
   with restricted access, through both ACL (see [Access Control List (ACL)          Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html)) or IAM.
4. Return the proper response, with the proper response code. I'm not sure, but it'd probably be similar to the payload below

```
{
    statusCode: 302,
    headers: {
      'Location': 'Your URL',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My project uses Lambda integration but I was able to get it working.

Comment: Glad you could get it to work! Would you mind posting how you did, in case somebody else has the same issue? Even just an outline